# Cassandra.ServerErrorException: 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadablePartial'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to do prepared insert via datastax c# cassandra driver and I am getting the following exception:

> Cassandra.ServerErrorException: 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadablePartial'

While trying to insert DateTime.Now

```
var prep = session.Prepare("Insert Into mytable (topic, post) Values (?, ?)");

var batch = new BatchStatement()
                .Add(prep.Bind("test", DateTime.Now));
session.Execute(batch);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your Cassandra setup - does it have the `joda-time-<version>.jar` file in the `lib` folder? It looks like it's missing, or you have 2 version of it (for example, left from the upgrade, etc. in this case remove all `joda-time` jars, and re-install libraries matching to your Cassandra version).